# Where is the data for work functions of simple metals?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, metals, data

I am looking for actual, published data on the work function of metals (Al, Au, Cu) that I can analyze by myself using Matlab. Google Scholar only offers published articles on the utilization of the data but not the data itself. Any leads as to where to further look are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The CRC Handbook is usually a good place to start looking. In addition, a HyperPhysics article recommends Ch.3 of Tipler and Llewellyn.

Comment: Kaye and Laby - http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_3/4_3.html

Comment: My observation is that students get a lot less practice looking in standard references these days (even knowing where the standard references are on the internet, much less cracking must old tomes).

Answer (score 2):

The [*CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics*](http://hbcponline.com/faces/contents/ContentsSearch.xhtml;jsessionid=5B7E0A417210C726F77EBB322ED76E04) has a decent compilation, as well as pointers to further references. This includes the metals you're explicitly interested in, for several different surface cut planes:

> [image]

The explicit references:

1. Hölzl, J., and Schulte, F. K., Work Functions of Metals, in *Solid Surface Physics*, Höhler, G., Ed., Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1979.
2. Riviere, J. C., Work Function: Measurements and Results, in *Solid State Surface Science*, Vol. 1, Green, M., Ed., Decker, New York, 1969.
3. Michaelson, H. B., *J. Appl. Phys.*, 48, 4729, 1977.